# Rewrite search page query URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want when search form submitted, the URL be like this :

`localhost/xampp/external/proj3/search/searchquery`

Instead of this:

`localhost/xampp/external/proj3/tools/search/search.php?query=searchquery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/external/proj3

# external redirect from action URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?query=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?query=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I think my condition in question wasn't clear enough.I've edited m question.please see it again.

Comment: First `RewriteRule` doesn't redirect. I should modify URL manually to work.

Comment: Root `http://localhost/xampp/external/proj3/` (htaccess file located here with `RewriteBase /xampp/external/proj3`)
The exact URL is : `http://localhost/xampp/external/proj3/search?query=h`
There is no more more rules about `search`

Comment: The `http://localhost/xampp/external/proj3/search?query=h` shows 404 error. but it works when changing to this `http://localhost/xampp/external/proj3/search/h `

Comment: Thanks. Finally worked !
You are **htaccess** hero :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your document root. And put this:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule     ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$   \
                search.php?query=$1 \
                [NC,L]
```

**Note**: Be careful with the regular expression. Filter it cautiously.

Comment: how can i convert this rule to redirect rule? my means if i write search.php?query=1 then redirect to search/1.